# What's the meaning of the expression "without the presence of God and Jesus."

Tags: phrases, phrase-meaning

When I was reading an article, I came across a particular phrase and couldn't figure it out.

> The secret formula of Coca-Cola is fiercely protected, so much so that
>   only two people who work at the company know the exact ingredients
>   that make up this unique soft drink. While this is a disappointment to
>   many, it's not at all surprising that one of the world's most
>   profitable companies wouldn't give away the formula of success so
>   easily.
>
> The only official written copy of the formula is said to be stored in
>   a US bank vault in Atlanta. In order to keep it safe, the company gave
>   the bank almost 50 million shares of stock and introduced some bizarre
>   policies to keep everyone away, such as:
>
> - The two people who know about the formula aren't allowed to fly on    the same plane.
> - No one can read the formula ***without the presence of God and Jesus***.

Comment: Some context could be helpful... could you link to the article or at the very least explain what the article is about? Is it [this article](http://www.careeraddict.com/19360/4-most-guarded-secrets-of-coca-cola)?

Comment: It’s hyperbole to say that access to the formula is so secretive that it would take a miracle to be allowed to read it.

Comment: I'm not a Christian apologist, but aren't God and Jesus (and the Holy Ghost) one thing, which is ubiquitous.  So isn't everybody always in the presence of God and Jesus?  Why would the two people not be allowed to fly on the same plane when the formula is stored in a vault?  Which vault, by the way, is in a Coke museum in Atlanta, not in a bank.  At least according to Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems logical to me that the two people who know the exact ingredients are humorously referred to as "God" and "Jesus" respectively, but somehow the article skipped that explanation. So it really only means "without the presence of the two people mentioned above".